# how to pass value in api body in protractor while requesting the api

Tags: javascript, api, automation, protractor, postman

I want to pass the value in API request body. 
I tried below code for that

```
    var options = { method: 'POST',
        url: 'https://ssgpreprod.serviceurl.in/gonogo-api/atm/tw/cro-approval',
        headers:
            { 'Postman-Token': '9d6a0ad1-c3a1-402f-b845-b6416f49df6b',
                'cache-control': 'no-cache',
                'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
        body:
            { oHeader:
                { sReqType: 'application/json',
                    sAppSource: 'WEB 2.02.01',
                    sSourceID: 'GONOGO_HDBFS',
                    sAppID: 610961419000670,
                    dtSubmit: '',
                    sCroId: 'HDB_TW_CRO@cell.com',
                    sDsaId: 'default',
                    sInstID: 4019,
                    sUserName: 'CHDBTWCRO',
                    sProduct: 'TW',
                    sDealerId: '61096' },
                sRefID:testData.twPreIpa.twReferenceId,
                sAppStat: testData.twCroDetails.twCroDecision,
                aCroJustification: [ { sRemark: testData.twCroDetails.twRemark, sSubTo: testData.twCroDetails.twSubjectTo} ],
                bApprAmtExist: true,
                dApprAmt: testData.twApplyDetails.twLoanAmount,
                dItrRt: testData.twCroDetails.twRoi,
                dLtv: testData.twCroDetails.twLtv,
                aDedupeRefID: [] },
        json: true };

    request(options, function (error, response, body) {
        if (error) throw new Error(error);
        browser.logger.info(JSON.stringify(body));
        browser.logger.info(JSON.stringify(response));
        browser.logger.info('status code is : ' + response.statusCode);
        expect(response.statusCode).toBe(200).then(function () {
            browser.logger.info('case is approved');
            this.logOut(testData);
        })
    });
```

I am passing value from xlsx file i.e testData.twPreIpa.twReferenceId but I am getting 422 status code and below output

[2019-05-28 15:42:10.403] [INFO] : - {"title":"Conversion Failed","status":422,"detail":"The content you've sent is probably malformed."}

Also, when I add - browser.logger.info('approved'); above var options it prints on console..  but when I add -             browser.logger.info(testData.twPreIpa.twReferenceId);

It gives me error .. ouput displayed -

Failed: Cannot read property 'twReferenceId' of undefined
TypeError: Cannot read property 'twReferenceId' of undefined

Comment: Where is request declared? Is it requiring the request npm package or another http package?

Comment: To me this looks like the api responding that you've sent a bad request. So the data you sent over is not in the format it is expecting. Also, this has absolutely nothing to do with protractor. Maybe `jasmine` but there is nothing here that is related to protractor.

Comment: @DublinDev request declared at the top of the page. 
var request = require("request");

Comment: @tehbeardedone
yes. that's what I am not getting how to pass the xlsx data in API thats why is is responding 422 status code. but if I pass normal value to it like 

sRefID: '21532562366' then it works for me. also I tried

sRefID:"testData.twPreIpa.twReferenceId"

sRefID:'testData.twPreIpa.twReferenceId'

Comment: @jenny maybe twPreIpa.twReferenceId is a Number and not a String?

Comment: @RedVarVar No. it's a string.
dLtv: testData.twCroDetails.twLtv .. This is no.. 
but both are not working.

Comment: @jenny did you try `sRefID:testData.twPreIpa.twReferenceId.toString()`?

Comment: @DublinDevyes tried.. It's giving below error

Failed: Cannot read property 'twReferenceId' of undefined
TypeError: Cannot read property 'twReferenceId' of undefined

also tried.. sRefID: ${testData.twPreIpa.twReferenceId}

it's giving 500 status code error

Comment: @jenny I've added an example of a similar protractor + request framework I've worked on. Aside from that it seems that your issue is with your excel data and not your request. I don't think it is reading your data how you expect. You should print it out to ensure it is

Comment: I second what @DublinDev is saying. Dump all your values to the console so you can see what they are. From the error you posted above it looks like `twPreIpa` is undefined. So whatever the value that is supposed to be there it's not picking up from your spreadsheet. Check that the variable names match. Capitalization, spelling, etc. I would just dump `testdata` to the console and verify all the values you expect are actually there. If not, figure out why they are missing.

Answer (score 0):

While this may not directly answer your question it should be helpful to you.
I worked on a similar framework to what (I assume) yours looks like,some api and some UI validations.

I had a separate class for my API calls which returned some value, sometimes the entire response body. I allowed myself the ability to pass in whatever body I needed as a parameter.

This is an example of the approach I took.

```
module.exports = class Endpoints {

    addSomethingToUser(bearerToken, userId, JSONbody) {
        //Function will preform a POST request and return the status code if successful
        //Else if will return the body of the response

        let endpoint = 'http://myApp.com:9090/api/users/' + userId;

        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            let options = {
                method: "POST",
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                    'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token,
                },
                body: JSON.stringify(JSONbody),
            };

            request(
                endpoint,
                options ,
                function (error, response, body) {
                    if (!error && (response.statusCode >= 200 && response.statusCode < 300)) {
                        resolve(response.statusCode);
                    } else {
                        console.log('error:', error, response && response.statusCode);
                        reject(JSON.stringify(response, undefined, 2));
                    };
                }
            );
        });
    };
}
```

It is called like

```
let apiCallsFile = require('../apiCalls/restCalls');
let apiCalls = new apiCallsFile();

it('simple test', async function(){
    let requiredBody = {
        "NAME": "Test Name",
        "GENDER": "MALE",
    };

    let apiResult = await apiCalls.addSomethingToUser(bearerToken, userId, requiredBody );
    expect(apiResult).toBe('201');
}
```

Your issue seems to be related to the actual values you are using from excel. You should attempt to print out your values before attempting to send the request to ensure they are all present and in the format you expect.